# Search within tag no longer works

Tags: bug, status-completed, tags, search

Searching something like `[r] test` used to allow to retrieve all the posts tagged with `r` and containing the word "test".

I noticed today that it doesn't work this way anymore. The `[r]` part of the query seems to be ignored:

[image: SO search for r test]

Note that on Meta we still have the expected behavior:

[image: MSO search for bug search]

Comment: Seems to work for me

Comment: I repro-ed this on main: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bc%23%5D+hello&mixed=0

Comment: No repro here (FF 60), rev 2018.6.22.30834. Perhaps copy the revision number at the bottom of the page?

Comment: I'm on Google Chrome and page is: rev 2018.6.22.30834

Comment: FF, Edge and IE seem to work for me, even when logged out Chrome doesn't work so it is not related to being logged in or not.

Comment: It's the 'C'.  When something weird happens, then if it's not Caching, it's Chrome:(

Comment: Can you post the urls?

Comment: The search which @rene linked is: working correctly for me in Firefox 52.8.1ESR, Microsoft Edge 42.17134.1.0, IE 11.48.17134.0, Opera 53.0.2907.99, Opera 53.0.2907.106, and Pale Moon 27.6.2. It is **not working** in Chrome  67.0.3396.87 (logged in or logged out), Firefox 60.0.2 and Pale Moon 27.9.3.

Comment: @Makyen is working for me on Chrome 67.0.3396.87.

Comment: What's changed?  Who has the side nav turned off? (grasping at straws now).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sorry about that. It should be fixed now. Thanks for reporting it.

Comment: Note that there are additional incorrect results, see [(wildcard characters) stopped working in search](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/369990/451475)