# Wildcard character (*) stopped working in search

Tags: bug, status-completed, search

For example `*crypt*` only returns hits on "crypt" and not "decrypt".

Examples:
1: `https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=*crypt*`
2: `https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=newest&q=*crypt*`
3: `https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=newest&q=decrypt`

Note that the results of URL 3 should appear in the results of URL 2.

This has happened in the past with updates, regression testing might be a good idea. Also global changes are best **not** done on a Friday afternoon.

## Update:

It appears that SO search meta-characters are working correctly when SO is accessed from EU/Deutschland but incorrectly when accessed from the US.

Comment: "Grep-like meta-character" somehow I thought this was going to be about a meta regular.

Comment: @Bret Copeland Re-stating: I want to see all questions that have the sequence size *crypt" in the question sorted newest first. This worked until earlier today. I use this so I can answer questions about encryption. This seems like a reasonable bug to report.

Comment: @zaph Isn't it more accurate to call it a wildcard character?

Comment: @zaph Unrelated to terminology, I'd say this is a confirmed bug, especially since it is intended behavior to match wild-carded results: https://stackoverflow.com/help/searching (last bullet point of first bullet point group).

Comment: Likely related to [Search within tag no longer works](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/369980/7296893), which has been [meta-tag:status-completed] today.

Comment: @ErikvonAsmuth Indeed, that is why I addressed a comment to Bret who responded to that report.

Comment: but that is not how user mentions work. They need to have participated on the post, either as commenter, editor or dupe-hammer. You can't out of the blue @JonSkeet to get him chime in ...

Comment: OK. It seems that Bret is the person involved in this issue based on his [answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/369986/451475). Sadly there seems to be no method to report SO bugs other than posting a question (which was immediately down voted) and hoping the right person will happen to see it and that person seems to be Bret.

Comment: If I try your example search it now works as designed, at least for me in Chrome (if this happens to be another crazy *works in one browser but not in another*)

Comment: @zaph I'm unable to reproduce `@rene`'s notation; it's the same amount of results in chrome as it is normally.  It is only reduced to 500 if you are logged out.

Comment: Unrelated but note that if you search for "polic", it will find results for "poly": https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=polic. The same is happening with "crypt" and "decrypt" and it counts results for similar words (like bcrypt or encrypt?).

Comment: @Holger `https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=newest&q=*crypt*`: 6,665 results, `https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=newest&q=encrypt`: 61,865 results. How can that be? The same result in Safari and Firefox when logged in.

Comment: Here, `*crypt*` has 290,255 results and `encrypt` has 67,730 results. Quiet plausible. Don’t know what’s different in your setup. But when the newest entry you see is one hour old, there must be a caching problem. I get twelve matches less than an hour old.

Comment: What is different is most likely the server, US vs EU/Deutschland. Perhaps the server you are using has a different update or the server you are hitting was not updated last Friday.

Comment: Can confirm 290,256 `*crypt*` results and 67,731 `encrypt` results. Also EU.

Comment: Hey zaph, we're indeed looking at this. We've been tweaking some code paths, and it's not clear yet what changed in regards to wildcards. We may roll back to an earlier version until it's sorted out.

Comment: @BretCopeland thank you for your comment: if possible, may you give us some conclusions or insights/follow-ups regarding this search issue using the "Post your answer" feature?

Answer (score 5):

Sorry about this. We have recently changed the search code and in doing so inadvertently broke the wildcard feature. It has now been fixed and should function normally.